# Fermentation lag-been almost 24 hours?

Tags: all-grain, fermentation-temperature

5.25 g all grain HIGH gravity (1.106)DIPA brewed yesterday, pitched 2 rehydrated US 05 packets about after I cooled to 60 degrees F, then aerated with pump for 30 minutes. I’ve had lags before when rehydrating, but never this long. At 22 hours, wort temp was 66 degrees (ambient) but with no activity still. I hit it with more oxygen, and am just waiting. Just need someone to tell me everything will be fine...?

Comment: First question in these cases always is: which kind of fermenter are you using? And, why do you assume that there is no fermentation?

Comment: Apologies. Fast Ferment conical 7.5 g

Comment: Your pitch rate seems good considering the gravity and the volume of your brew. Are you sure that your fermenter does not leak somewhere?

Comment: Not 100% positive I guess. Last time I used it it worked great. I’m using a blowoff tube to a growler with sanitizer in it...could be some loss there I suppose. I could switch to an airlock, just defaulted to the blowoff expecting a pretty aggressive fermentation. There’s a ton of head space though so airlock should probably be ok regardless.

Comment: It's probably more difficult to see with this type of fermenter how the wort currently looks. Can you see if the border between beer and air on the inside of the fermenter is clean or dirty? If it is clean then there is indeed no fermentation. If it is dirty, then that would be a sure sign that there was kraüsen and that there is active fermentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very high OG and pretty cool to start with.

Its actually about only 50% of the pitch it needed for that OG.  Your growth phase will be longer, I would add two more packs of yeast and raise temp to 68° and hold it there.

But it should take off within the next 48 hours if nothing is done. But you may get some growth esters you done want.

Comment: Safe to add more packs now, which would be 36-48 hours into fermentation?

Comment: @ts_watson I would expect within 24 hours with the added pitch, if you get the temp up a couple degrees.

Comment: Update: it’s definitely taken off, started yesterday afternoon and quite active now. To be clear-adding another pack or two 2 at this point would NOT have a negative affect? I didn’t realize that was such an under pitch :( temp is now 68.

Comment: @ts_watson it's fine to add it now. Would be better sooner than later.

Comment: would one more round of oxygen be beneficial for the sake of pitch #2? Not quite 72 hours total from initial pitch, but less than 24 hours from second pitch

Comment: @ts_watson on technique in super high grav brewing is to add O2 several times during fermentation. But stop once the SG is within 50% of the FG. (1/2 the alcohol has been made)

Comment: Will do-thanks (as always) for the generosity to assist/advise-even after 45 batches, the questions seem to keep coming. Very appreciative of the helpful answers!

Comment: just wanted to update: The FG ended one point away from my 70% efficiency expectations after all, and the beer turned out fantastic.  Thanks again for the help!